# mvc set value of dropdownlist via jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a variable number of dropdownlists in my view. I am trying to prepopulate their values based on a viewmodel property. I have reviewed similar questions on this site and others and most suggestions say to use .prop or .val to set the value however I am getting the error `....is not a function` when attempting to do so. Basically I iterate through my dropdownlists and try to set the value of each to the value of `eachQuantifier[i]`.All help is appreciated, my code is below:

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    var stringifiedQuantifiers = "@Model.StringifiedSubIngredientQuantifiers";
    var eachQuantifier = stringifiedQuantifiers.split(";");
    var dropdownlists = $(".dropdownlist");
    for (var i = 0; dropdownlists.length; i++) {
      var dropdown = dropdownlists[i];
      dropdown.val(eachQuantifier[i]);
    }

  });
```

and the dropdownlists themselves are built as:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRecipeUnit, Model.BaseUnitOptions, "Select Unit", new { @class = "form-control dropdownlist", @data_key = @Model.IngredientIdNamePairs.ElementAt(i).Key })
```

Comment: `$(dropdown).val(....`

Comment: @Stephen this results in the page freezing (loading indefinitely) on load

Comment: Then you have other problems (not the least is that your generating your controls incorrectly - you need a `for` loop - but thats not related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are iterating through the elements in `dropdownlists`, you are accessing the DOM-elements found.

You need to access the jquery objects by using:

```
$(dropdown).val(...)
```

Comment: this results in the page freezing (loading indefinitely) on load

Comment: How many elements are found with `.dropdownlist´? Have you tried to step through that code with a Debugger attached? Seems that there is some other kind of problem with your code.